# How to avoid performing a firebase function on folders on cloud storage events

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to organize assets(images) into folders with a unique id for each asset, the reason being that each asset will have multiple formats (thumbnails, and formats optimized for web and different viewports).

So for every asset that I upload to the folder `assets-temp/` is then moved and renamed by the functions into `assets/{unique-id}/original{extension}`.

example: `assets-temp/my-awesome-image.jpg` should become `assets/489023840984/original.jpg`.

note: I also keep track of the files with their original name in the DB and in the original's file metadata.

**The issue**: The function runs and performs what I want, but it also adds a folder named `assets/{uuid}/original/` with nothing in it...

The function:

```
exports.process_new_assets = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  // Run this function only for files uploaded to the "assets-temp/" folder.
  if (!object.name.startsWith('assets-temp/')) return null;

  const file = bucket.file(object.name);
  const fileExt = path.extname(object.name);
  const destination = bucket.file(`assets/${id}/original${fileExt}`);
  const metadata = {
    id,
    name: object.name.split('/').pop()
  };

  // Move the file to the new location.
  return file.move(destination, {metadata});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am **guessing** that this might happen if the operation of uploading the original image triggers two separate events: one that creates the directory assets-temp and one that creates the file assets-temp/my-awesome-image.jpg.

If I guessed right, the first operation will trigger your function with a directory object (named `"assets-temp/"`). This matches your first `if`, so the code will proceed and do

```
destination = bucket.file('assets/${id}/original') // fileExt being empty
```

and then call file.move - this will create `assets/id/original/` directory.

Simply improve your 'if' to exclude a file named "assets-temp/".

Comment: You are correct, that is the issue. But inst there a way of checking if the object is a folder?

Comment: I don't know much about the Firebase functions, never worked with them, actually. I solved this simply by thinking what could possibly trigger the creation of an extra folder. You should look through the documentation - and it is indeed a good idea to check if what you got is a folder, no matter what the name is (someone can trip you by creating a folder named 'assets-temp/something.jpeg/', too).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) there is no such thing as folders in cloud storage, however, it is possible to emulate them, like you can do by using the console GUI. When creating folders what really happens is that an empty object is created(zero bytes of space) but its name ends with a forward slash, also folder names can end with `_$folder$` but it is my understanding that that is how things worked in older versions so for newer buckets the forward slash is enough.